# When I create a partition on a non-partitioned disk, does that automatically create a "partition table"?

Tags: partition, usb-drive

When I create a partition on a non-partitioned disk, does that automatically create a "partition table"?

For ie, with a flash drive, hard drive, any format (ext4; FAT).

Comment: Yes, because the concept partition only exist on a disk with partition table.but you make sure you create a partition. Not anything else

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Partitions need to reside in tables.
You can store data without partitioning, but that's not what you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

There are several kinds of partitions, and the term "partition table" refers to a specific kind (DOS partitions), so, strictly speaking, you can have partitions without a partition table.

OTOH ALL partitioning schemes (I know of) rely on some data structure written to disk itself so, in a broader sense, every partition needs "some kind of" partition table.

In general all programs responsible for partion creation also initialize the relevant data structure, if not already available.